# MariaDB default function changing PK field with auto increment to null

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Take the example of the following query, I am inserting data to the teams table and teamId (type: INT) is the primary key with auto-increment set to true.

```
'INSERT INTO `teams` (`teamId`,`teamName`,`referralCommission`,`createdAt`,`updatedAt`,`companyId`) VALUES (DEFAULT,?,?,?,?,?);'
```

This query runs fine on MySQL, but on MariaDB the DEFAULT is being converted to null, which I know is the normal behavior when the default is not set for a column. But in my case, the teamId is auto-incremented so the default should point to the next available id. Instead, teamId is set to 0 (converts from null) for all entries and since the teamId is primary key, I am unable to add new entries to the table.

Any way I can use the default function of MySQL in mariadb? or any other solution for this problem.

P.S I know I can remove the teamId field entirely from the query and it will work, but I need the above query to work as it is.

Comment: If you have an autoincrement column, you typically don't need to add a value at all for it in the insert query ie `INSERT into teams (teamname, referralCommission, ..) values (?,?..)` Note the missing `teamId` and `DEFAULT` value. If that doesn't work, share your table definition.

Comment: If that column *really*  is a autoincrement column, it will insert the next `int` even if you explicitely specify `NULL` as value. Ie something like `insert into team(teamid, ...) values (NULL, ...)` will still insert the next number and not null

Comment: @derpirscher Yes, what you mentioned works, removing the teamId and the DEFAULT works fine. But I need to make the query run like it is. I am using Sequelize to connect to MariaDB via Express.JS. Unfortunately, whenever Sequelize runs the create function it sends the query with the primary key set as DEFAULT.

Comment: Also `DEFAULT` works fine. See this fiddle (https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=c7e1c2f89100e9cdcdd801be8d96bdd9) Therefore I asked for the exact table definition. Because if your query doesn't work, it's likely that there is something wrong with your table definition.

Comment: @derpirscher I tried explicitly setting the teamId to null in the sequelize create function and it works! Previously, I was not providing the value for the teamId to the sequelize function and by default, it adds DEFAULT. Now it's working. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

i cant say what you doing. which MariaDB version you are using ?

**sample**

```
   MariaDB [bernd]> SELECT VERSION();
    +----------------------------------------+
    | VERSION()                              |
    +----------------------------------------+
    | 10.2.41-MariaDB-1:10.2.41+maria~bionic |
    +----------------------------------------+
    1 row in set (0.06 sec)
    
    MariaDB [bernd]>

    MariaDB [bernd]> TRUNCATE pk_default;
    Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.09 sec)
    
    MariaDB [bernd]> SELECT * FROM `pk_default`;
    Empty set (0.01 sec)
    
    MariaDB [bernd]> INSERT INTO `pk_default` (`id`, `sid`, `val`)
        -> VALUES
        -> (DEFAULT, 6, 45);
    Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
    
    MariaDB [bernd]> SELECT * FROM `pk_default`;
    +----+-----+------+
    | id | sid | val  |
    +----+-----+------+
    |  1 |   6 |   45 |
    +----+-----+------+
    1 row in set (0.00 sec)
    
    MariaDB [bernd]> INSERT INTO `pk_default` (`id`, `sid`, `val`)
        -> VALUES
        -> (DEFAULT, 6, 45);
    Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)
    
    MariaDB [bernd]> SELECT * FROM `pk_default`;
    +----+-----+------+
    | id | sid | val  |
    +----+-----+------+
    |  1 |   6 |   45 |
    |  2 |   6 |   45 |
    +----+-----+------+
    2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
    
    MariaDB [bernd]> INSERT INTO `pk_default` (`id`, `sid`, `val`)
        -> VALUES
        -> (DEFAULT, 6, 45);
    Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
    
    MariaDB [bernd]> SELECT * FROM `pk_default`;
    +----+-----+------+
    | id | sid | val  |
    +----+-----+------+
    |  1 |   6 |   45 |
    |  2 |   6 |   45 |
    |  3 |   6 |   45 |
    +----+-----+------+
    3 rows in set (0.01 sec)
    
    MariaDB [bernd]>
```